# Combining 2 select statements together in one query

Tags: php, mysql

I need to combine 2 select statements together but i get an error:

> Notice: Trying to get property of non-object

My code currently:

```
$sql = "(SELECT id, sijainti FROM sijainti
  UNION ALL
SELECT numero FROM tiedot)";
```

My code works perfectly otherwise if i try to do this only with one select statement. Any suggestions for making this work?

Answer (score 0):

If you use UNION then number of fetched column must be equal, also name of columns must be same, so modify your query like,

$sql = "(SELECT id AS id, sijainti AS name FROM sijainti UNION ALL SELECT 0 as id, numero AS name FROM tiedot)";

may be it will help you,

Comment: I didn' get it to work, but could this be done with JOIN somehow?

Comment: visit this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475850/how-can-an-sql-query-return-data-from-multiple-tables